# Why std::cout print a Octal Number without a 0 in the beginning of the number

Tags: c++

If I run this snippet of code

```
int main()
 {
   int i = 8;
   std::cout << std::oct << i;
 }
```

The console shows 10.

Shouldn't give 010, in C++ Octal Numbers start with 0.

Comment: `std::cout << std::oct << "0" << i;`

Comment: What hinders you to add leading zeroes as you like/need?

Comment: `std::showbase` exists for a reason.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That would be good as an answer. I think this question is reasonable. I have not even come across `std::showbase` before. Learn something every day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [std::showbase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase) for this.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
   int i = 100;
   std::cout << "100 without showbase:\n";
   std::cout << "decimal: " << std::dec << i << "\n";
   std::cout << "    hex: " << std::hex << i << "\n";
   std::cout << "  octal: " << std::oct << i << "\n";
   std::cout << "100 with showbase:\n";
   std::cout << "decimal: " << std::showbase << std::dec << i << "\n";
   std::cout << "    hex: " << std::showbase << std::hex << i << "\n";
   std::cout << "  octal: " << std::showbase << std::oct << i << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
100 without showbase:
decimal: 100
    hex: 64
  octal: 144
100 with showbase:
decimal: 100
    hex: 0x64
  octal: 0144
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sqqMvf7Ev)